# Lorentz force separation from induction in rotating loop within AC magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

I was wondering , is it possible to create a loop of any kind of geometry that could rotate in a non homogeneous AC magnetic field and have no net induction within the loop but only have current generated from the effect of Lorentz force on the electrons in the moving conductor ? It is achieved easily in a static magnetic field.
In changing magnetic field this in theory can be achieved either by avoiding forming loops around areas of flux or by forming loops with canceling flux between them.
I asked this to chatGPT and got an answer that in theory it could be possible but then i tried to draw out loops on paper and soon realized it might not be possible after all.

Another interesting aspect is that when i tried to see the direction of current in the loop as it rotates within a AC magnetic field that is bipolar for example like those found in universal motor stators , it seems to me the direction of the Lorentz force generated current in the loop is the same as that generated by induction, is this always the case in loops rotating in AC fields?

Comment: > *have no net induction within the loop but only have current generated from the effect of Lorentz force on the electrons in the moving conductor ?* What do you mean by no net induction, that circulation of electric field is zero? What do you mean by Lorentz force, electric plus magnetic force or just the magnetic part?

Comment: @Ján Lalinský I mean just the magnetic part, because all other parts and additions form induction within a loop, my curiosity is about whether one can have a loop without induction effects of any kind where any current generated is solely from the deflection force on electrons created by movement through a magnetic field, whether static or time varying

Answer (score 1):

EMF in a loop of wire is, in general, not exactly the integral of the electric field $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf v\times\mathbf B$, as sometimes tacitly assumed:

$$
\mathscr{E} \approx  \oint_\gamma \mathbf E \cdot d\mathbf s + \mathbf v\times \mathbf B\cdot d\mathbf s. 
$$

For example, consider a rigid planar loop of wire translating in electrostatic field of a stationary point charge, the lines of force of electric field lying in the plane of the loop. Thus the charge is at rest in the lab reference frame, and the loop is translating. Since in the loop frame there is, in general, a changing magnetic flux through the loop, there is non-zero net EMF in the loop, and appropriate non-zero current. But in the lab frame, the above integral vanishes; so the integral does not give value of EMF accurately in this case.

Thus we see that even when the electric part of the above integral vanishes, this does not mean that the EMF is due to motional EMF due to magnetic field. In the example, EMF is still due to electric field, just the circulation integral does not quantify it correctly.

A better formula for the net EMF is based on electric field $\mathbf E'$ in the frame of the wire loop(assuming it moves uniformly):

$$
\mathscr{E} = \oint_\gamma \mathbf E' \cdot d\mathbf s.
$$

Since approximately for small velocities we have $\mathbf E' \approx \mathbf E  + \mathbf v \times \mathbf B$, we get the approximate integral above, but we see why it is only approximate.

This shows that all EMF can be thought as due to electric field only, in the frame of the wire element; there the element has zero velocity, so there is no motional EMF due to motion in magnetic field.

We can try to transform this into the lab frame, but the exact formula will be more complicated that the integral above, taking into account length contraction and field values at different times at different positions, and distinguishing the EMF contribution due to electric field and due to motion in magnetic field becomes, in general, quite difficult.

Comment: I don't see why the integral vanishes in the lab frame, can you elaborate? Charge is induced on the loop while it passes by the stationary charge. Currents result since the loop is in motion, yielding a time-varying magnetic flux through the loop. On an unrelated note, I find it a little easier to visualize the fields and the currents by replacing the point charge with a uniformly charged line segment that runs along the direction of motion. Its motion in the loop frame emulates current flow in an ordinary wire, when it's close to the loop.

Comment: @Ján Lalinský  I am not sure I understood your answer. I was analyzing this from a B field perspective. on a piece of paper making drawings I concluded that once you form a loop , there is no possible geometry that doesn't get varying flux through it as it rotates in a non uniform , non homogeneous magnetic field therefore if the field is static the loop will get induced current that has a frequency that matches to rotational frequency of the loop and if the B field is AC then the current will have a frequency that is the sum of RPM+ AC field frequency.

Comment: @Puk the integral vanishes when $\mathbf E$ is field of the static charge, because this field is conservative. In the frame of the loop, field of the charge $\mathbf E'$ is not conservative, and the integral does not vanish. This latter integral doesn't depend on the induced surface charge on the loop surface; this charge can be made arbitrarily small by assuming the loop is made of an arbitrarily thin wire; thus it has arbitrarily small contribution to electric field, and cannot explain the EMF. The EMF is due to external electric field.

Comment: @Girts The point of my answer is that it is not always correct to classify the EMF as "due to motion in magnetic field", as opposed "due to induced electric field". Thus the question seems based on a misconception that we can easily define, for a moving loop, which part is due to induced electric field, and which part is motional. In general, this is not easy. Where it is easy is in the frame of the translating loop - non-zero EMF is purely due to an induced electric field.

Comment: @Girts In the case of a rotating loop, the loop is a non-inertial frame, and EMF in its frame is due to both effective electric field there, and (a very minor effect in practice) due to centrifugal force.

Comment: @Girts it is possible to have zero variation of flux - just make the loop rotate in just the right way, following the rotating magnetic field, so that flux through the loop does not change. However, this means zero net EMF (induced+motional), not zero induced EMF.

Comment: @Ján Lalinský Well , the simplest form of a non homogeneous magnetic field is a two pole field. N-S, if such a field exists and the source of that field is stationary when the loop is rotating then no matter the loop geometry there will always be some flux variation through the loop as it rotates. If I rotate the B field source with the loop then the flux variation disappears but so does the EMF in the stationary reference frame. No current generation in the loop. It seems to me that the only B field that can solely generate current in a moving loop on Lorentz force alone is homopolar

Comment: > *It seems to me that the only B field that can solely generate current in a moving loop on Lorentz force alone is homopolar* I don't see what you mean. For rotating loop, any static magnetic field will do - it is the kinetic energy of the loop (or work of forces turning the loop around) that generates the current. Magnetic field just enables this transfer.

Comment: @Ján Lalinský Think of the classic DC generator. It is actually an AC machine, the loop rotates in a static N-S B field but it's the changing flux through the loop as it rotates that actually generates the current. I am not disputing that kinetic energy is responsible for current generation. But remember my original question, try to come up with a loop geometry that can rotate in a non uniform B field that gets current generation solely from the magnetic field caused deflection of the moving electrons and not from change of flux? It seems to me only a homogeneous and uniform homopolar field

Comment: I interpreted your question as whether one can have EMF that is not due to induced electric field but due to motional EMF due to motion of the wire in magnetic field. This is not the same as EMF with zero change in magnetic flux; I think there is a misconception here. The motional EMF due to motion of the wire in magnetic field is taken into account correctly by Faraday's law, which gives EMF as rate of change of magnetic flux in time. If the magnetic flux through the winding does not change in time, net emf is zero.

Comment: In the DC motor, motional EMF due to motion in magnetic field corresponds to non-zero rate of change of magnetic flux through the winding. Perhaps by "not from change of flux" you really mean "not from magnetic field changing in time in the lab frame where the loop rotates"?

Comment: @Ján Lalinský are you aware of the Faraday disc aka homopolar generator ?

Comment: @Ján Lalinský  There the source of a static homogeneous field that has a symmetry around the axis of rotation can be either stationary or rotate with the disc , either way current is generated. The current is because of Lorentz force , charged particles moving through magnetic field. But if the field is not homogeneous and symmetrical around axis of rotation then it cannot rotate with the disc but has to be stationary, if it rotates then there is no current. I find this strange. There is no current even if the rest of the loop is shielded from flux and made to rotate together with the magnet

Comment: > *if it rotates then there is no current* I don't think this is correct - if the field is asymmetric, it won't be as simple as in the symmetric case, but motional EMF will be present in the rotating disc and some complicated current distribution in the disc will be as well. Maybe ask another question about the Faraday disc, with a picture of the geometry of the magnetic field and disc. I am not sure what exactly do you have in mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150622/discussion-between-girts-and-jan-lalinsky).

Comment: @JánLalinský Thanks, I agree with these conclusions when the wire is arbitrarily thin. However, how does an observer in the lab frame explain the current since they calculate zero emf? What force do they conclude is responsible for pushing charge around the loop? I might ask this as a separate question at some point because this might be somewhat off-topic for this question, and also not necessarily easy to answer in comments.

Comment: @Puk they calculate zero emf only if using the approximate formula, the first formula above. The correct formula to use seems to be the second one, both in loop's frame and in lab's frame.

Comment: @Ján Lalinský please look at the chat I wrote some information there